# Calculating log-likelihood for given MLE (Markov Chains)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, markov-process, likelihood

I am currently working with Markov chains and calculated the Maximum Likelihood Estimate using transition probabilities as suggested by several sources (i.e., number of transitions from a to b divided by number of overall transitions from a to other nodes).

I now want to calculate the log-likelihood of the MLE.

Comment: You've already computed the maximum likelihood estimate of the transition probabilities and now you want to compute the log-likelihood of what exactly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let $ \{ X_i \}_{i=1}^{T}$ be a path of the markov chain and let $P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_T)$ be the probability of observing the path when $\theta$ is the true parameter value (a.k.a. the likelihood function for $\theta$). Using the definition of conditional probability, we know

$$ P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_T)  = P_{\theta}(X_T | X_{T-1}, ..., X_1) \cdot P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_{T-1})$$

Since this is a markov chain, we know that $P_{\theta}(X_T | X_{T-1}, ..., X_1) = P_{\theta}(X_T | X_{T-1} )$, so this simplifies this to

$$ P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_T)  = P_{\theta}(X_T | X_{T-1}) \cdot P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_{T-1})$$

Now if you repeat this same logic $T$ times, you get

$$ P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_T)  = \prod_{i=1}^{T} P_{\theta}(X_i | X_{i-1} ) $$

where $X_0$ is to be interpreted as the initial state of the process. The terms on the right hand side are just elements of the transition matrix. Since it was the log-likelihood you requested, the final answer is:

$$ {\bf L}(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{T} \log \Big( P_{\theta}(X_i | X_{i-1} ) \Big) $$

This is the likelihood of a single markov chain - if your data set includes several (independent) markov chains then the full likelihood will be a sum of terms of this form.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the answer.
In this case $P_{\theta}$ is the "transition" probability taken from the MLE, right?

Comment: @ph_singer, you are very welcome. $P_{\theta}(X_i|X_{i-1})$ is the probability of moving from state $X_{i-1}$ to $X_i$, given the parameter value, $\theta$. If you imposed no structure on the transition matrix (which is what it sounds like) then $\theta$ just denotes the vector of transition probabilities (and the MLEs are just the sample proportions, as you correctly indicated in your question statement), so, yes:  $P_{\hat{\theta}_{{\rm MLE}}}(X_i|X_{i-1})$ will just be the sample proportion of moves from state $X_{i-1}$ that ended up in state $X_{i}$.

Comment: Thanks again! Just one more question: If I use another order (e.g., k=2), how would this process work then?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "order"?

Comment: (+1) The OP probably means $k=2$ to denote a *second-order* MC, i.e., depending on the previous two states $X_{i-1},X_{i-2}$ rather than just the most recent one $X_{i-1}$.

Comment: @ph_singer, if cardinal's interpretation is correct, then I think the basic logic remains the same and the final product becomes $\prod_{i=2}^{T} P_{\theta}(X_i | X_{i-1}, X_{i-2} )$.

Comment: Okay, that sounds logic ;)

Comment: @ph_singer, the above expression is for the _likelihood_ but the standard theory (I assume you are calculating the maximized log-likelihood for, e.g. a likelihood ratio test) applies to the _log-likelihood_ and the product becomes a sum when you take logs.

Comment: @ph_singer, I am a little confused about *"I am testing which MLE maximizes the likelihood for my given data"* - there's only one MLE and it is the sample proportions, as you noted in your original post. If you are talking about comparing two models, when one model is more constrained than the other, comparing the likelihoods is not enough - you  need to account for the difference in the dimension of the parameter (e.g. see [the likelihood ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test)) - it is impossible for the less constrained model to have a lower maximized likelihood.

Comment: @Macro I want to test whether a k=1 order model is more likely than a k=2 order model. Now I would build two different MLEs (one for k=1 and one for k=2) and then calculate the log-likelihood for both on the data and compar it.

Comment: @ph_singer, ok, I see. Well, the $k=2$ model cannot possibly have lower maximized log-likelihood, since the $k=1$ case is a sub-model of it, so inspecting the likelihoods alone will not tell you whether the $k=2$ model was worth the added complexity. I'd suggest using the likelihood ratio test, which says that twice the difference in the maximized log-likelihood is asymptotically $\chi^2$ distributed with degrees of freedom equal to the difference in the number of parameters (transition probabilities, in this case) in the two models. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Macro Yeah, that helps, I will look into that. I hope I am not shifting too far from the original topic, but I got another question. Suppose I want to generate a k=1 model (this is straight forward) and a k=2 model. I would then reduce the higher order model to a k=1 model. The data I have is a set of paths and I would connect them to one. So given: 1 - 2 - 3 and 4 - 5 - 6 with a reset state 0 I would generate a trail for k=2: 0 - 0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 0 - 0 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 0 then I get a new state space with 0, 00, 01, 12 etc. After encoding this I get a simple k=1 chain. Is this process correct?

Comment: @ph_singer, if there is no structure to the model then I think it is correct to formulate a $k=2$ chain by viewing the combination of the two previous states as the "previous state" in a $k=1$ chain, but I'd need to think about it more carefully. If you have further questions, I suggest posting another question, as the comments are not intended for extended discussions like this :) I hope this exchange has helped.

Comment: That's what I thought. This exchange helped a lot @Macro. Thanks again.